# Magento 2: Add UI Multiselect Dropdown

Tags: magento2, category-tree, multiselect-attribute

How can I add categories multiselect (same as one used on product page - screen) to my custom module?

[image: Magento2 categories multiselect]

Edit:
Following @PrincePatel suggestion I have rewritten part of my code to use ui_component. The following code is working (though not doing what I am looking for) and displays grid with one column:

> app/code/Patryk/Test/view/adminhtml/ui_component/patryk_test_config_categories.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
  <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">patryk_test_config_categories.patryk_test_config_listing_data_source</item>
      <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">patryk_test_config_categories.patryk_test_config_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">patryk_test_config_columns</item>
  </argument>
  <dataSource name="patryk_test_config_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
      <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">PatrykTestConfigGridDataProvider</argument>
      <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">patryk_test_config_listing_data_source</argument>
      <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
        </item>
      </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
      </item>
    </argument>
  </dataSource>
  <columns name="patryk_test_config_columns">
    <column name="status">
      <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">status</item>
        </item>
      </argument>
    </column>
  </columns>
</listing>
```

I have tried to change listing to form and insert  inside (like [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-module-form-uicomponent/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sampleform_form.xml)), but it doesn't work (form is not showing and spinner keeps spinning forever). How to change the code to display categories selector? I don't need it to connect with any data, just display all categories and allow selection like on screen, because I am planning to handle this with JavaScript.

Edit2:
I have created empty data provider

```
namespace Patryk\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Grid;

class Emptycollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{
    public function getData(){
        return [];
    }
}
```

And custom_ui form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
  <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">patryk_test_config_categories2.patryk_test_config_categories2_data_source</item>
      <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">patryk_test_config_categories2.patryk_test_config_categories2_data_source</item>
    </item>
  </argument>
  <dataSource name="patryk_test_config_categories2_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
      <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Patryk\Test\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Grid\Emptycollection</argument>
      <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">patryk_test_config_categories2_data_source</argument>
      <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
      </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
      </item>
    </argument>
  </dataSource>
  <fieldset name="sample_fieldset">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sample Fieldset</item>
      </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="status">
      <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
          <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
          <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
          <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
          <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
          <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
          <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
          </item>
          <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
          </item>
          <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
        </item>
      </argument>
    </field>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

But it returns an error (simple pop-up alert saying Attention - Something went wrong.) without any further info in logs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a code example with a solution by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<field name="category_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category_id</item>
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```